# How to show that two random variables are equal (almost everywhere)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, A,P)$ be some probability space where $A$ is a sigma algebra over $\Omega$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $E(X^2) <\infty$, $E(Y^2)<\infty$ and assume $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$. Furthermore we know $$ 0 = E((X-Y)^2).$$

Now I need to show that there is an $M\subset \Omega$ such that $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in M$ and $P(M) = 1$.

It makes intuitively sense but I struggle to show this rigorously, I started out using

$$0 = E((X-Y)^2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2 f_{X-Y}(t) dt$$

where $f_{X-Y}$ is the probability density of $X-Y$ Since any density is nonnegative we know that $f_{X-Y}$ is zero almost everywhere.

How can I now come to the conclusion? I have the impression that the last statement alone is not sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show that $P(Z>0)=0$ where $Z=|X-Y|$, knowing that $E(Z^2)=0$.
By Chebyshev's inequality, for all $a>0$, you know $P(Z>a)\le E(Z^2)/a^2 = 0$.
But the event $[Z>0] = \bigcup_{n>0} [Z>1/n]$, so $P(Z>0)\le \sum_{n>0} P(Z>1/n) \le \sum_{n>0} 0 = 0.$